# How to reference external xml files in BeanIO?

Tags: java, xml, javabeans, bean-io

I've been reading the templates section from BeanIO but I haven't found anything specific to external files with templates. Basically, I am trying to create a xml file that will hold all my templates and reference a specific template from other files.

I have this file mytemplates.xml

```
<beanio>

    <template name="theTemplate">
        //template fields
    </template>
</beanio>
```

and I have another file called myfile.xml that will use the templates from mytemplates.xml

```
<beanio>
    <stream name="aaa" format="fixedlength">
            <include template="theTemplate"/>
    </stream>
</beanio>
```

is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference I found the answer navigating through the repo and someone mentioned it on the beanIO group also. Hope it helps.

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">



<--I had to go up to package level to make it work ie: org/app/myapp/mytemplates.xml-->
  <import resource="classpath:mytemplates.xml"/>

  <!-- the rest of your file -->
</beanio>
```